# passing parameters in nested views with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am running into trouble understanding how you can correctly pass parameters using AngularJS.

This is the code I was trying to use in my app.js file for the nested views, however, the nest state never properly renders.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('news', {
    url: '/news',
    templateUrl: 'templates/news.html',
    controller: 'NewsCtrl'
  })

  .state('news.id', {
    url: '/news/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/news.id.html',
    controller: 'NewsCtrl'
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/news');
})
```

It will try and change the url to #/news/news/:id versus just #/news/:id.

And if I try and change the path to just be the #/news/:id, then the pages do not render correctly.

What is the best approach to achieve these nested views with parameters?

Comment: news.html is the layout or listing page?

Answer (score 2):

According to [ui-route wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states):

> When using url routing together with nested states the default
>   behavior is for child states to append their url to the urls of each
>   of its parent states.
>
> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix
>   your url string with a special symbol '^'.

So in your case, you should try

```
 .state('news.id', {
    url: '^/news/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/news.id.html',
    controller: 'NewsCtrl'
  });
```